# container stopped being able to connect database container on same machine

Tags: docker

I have two Docker containers running on the same Ubuntu 16.04 machine.
A Golang web server publishing port 443 and a Postgres database server publishing port 5432.

On March 5 the web server was no longer able to connect to the Postgres container with a getsockopt connection timeout error. I can connect to the Postgres server remotely just fine.

I tried changing the Postgres connection host string in my Golang server from my machine's ip to localhost and 0.0.0.0 and neither worked.
I'm using UFW, tried a few different things I found through searching but no luck there. I assume it would have blocked the connection outright and not timed out anyways.

Tried numerous other things, the only thing I can think of is the March 1 update of Docker.

If you need more information just let me know.

Run Commands:

```
docker run -dit -p 5432:5432 --restart always --name postgres_container_name -v /mnt/db1:/db -e PGDATA=/db/data postgres_image_name

docker run -dit -p 443:443 --log-driver=syslog --restart always --name go_container_name go_image_name
```

I use my machine's ip as host and it defaults to the postgres port.
Example error from golang, replacing my ip address with a placeholder:

```
[CRIT] dial tcp MY_IP:5432: getsockopt: connection timed out
```

I can run the Golang server on my remote machine just fine, it connects. Just running it on the container on the same machine it times out even though it was working before. I have had this problem before and running this fixed it:

```
ufw allow in on docker0
```

It appears these rules are still in place and working, I even tried turned off ufw and still no luck.

Comment: How do you run those containers? Could you post the exact commands? Also, through which address (ip:port) do you instruct Golang server to connect to the Postgres server?